# Sql Server Data Tools without Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm studying Sql Server Data Tools (SSDT). Do I need a Visual Studio 2010 / 2012? Can I use a express edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSDT replaces Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) from SQL Server 2008, regarding Integration Services, Analysis Services and Reporting Services. When you install SQL Server 2012, you get an option to install SSDT. In this case, SSDT will be installed in an empty shell of Visual Studio 2010, with nothing but the BI project types (Integration Services project, Analysis Services project, etc.)

If you are talking about the non-BI related features of SSDT (Database Project, Database unit testing, etc.) you need a pre-installed version of Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, Express edition is not supported.

Comment: Yeah, I was asking about the non BI features. Thanks. I'll mark your as the correct answer. Thank you =]

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express Edition is not supported by SSDT.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/89574dc9-3a1f-44b9-b14c-bce29fd2ceaf/does-ms-visual-studion-2012-express-contain-ssdt

Answer (score 1):

SSDT with VS 2015 can be installed without having Visual Studio, and SSDT will install Visual Studio with the limited features needed for SSDT, HOWEVER you must be sure to install .NET Framework 4.5 before trying to install SSDT. If .NET Framework 4.5 is not present, the installer will fail immediately, and most likely will tell you that you need Visual Studio.  I ran into this while trying to install on Windows Server 2008 R2, and everything worked well once .NET Framework 4.5 was installed.

Comment: Newer versions of SSDT are only available as part of Visual Studio.  For most companies, this probably does not increase licensing costs, since the [Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition License](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt031819/) contains special terms around using it solely for SQL development.

Answer (score 0):

SSDT is included in most Visual Studio 2013 Express editions, and for earlier versions of Visual Studio you can download a free standalone install from the web. All of the available install options are [listed on the download page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027). Take a look there and hopefully one of the options will suit you.